# Regex Search/Match Python CSV

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do the following.

1. read in a csv file with multiple fields (i have put a copy of the file below, with only a few of the fields

-

```
**Job Title,Department**
"443.ENGINEER IV - INFORMATION SECURITY","INFORMATION SECURITY"
"443.MANAGER - INFORMATION SECURITY","INFORMATION SECURITY"
"443.SENIOR THREAT INTELLIGENCE MANAGER","INFORMATION SECURITY"
"443.SR ENGINEER - INFORMATION SECURITY","INFORMATION SECURITY"
"443.SR MANAGER - INFORMATION SECURITY","INFORMATION SECURITY"
"543.ENGINEER III - INFRASTRUCTURE","RELATIONAL LAB"
"543.MANAGER - SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT","RELATIONAL LAB"
"543.SR ENGINEER - DEVELOPMENT","RELATIONAL LAB"
"543.SR ENGINEER - INFRASTRUCTURE","RELATIONAL LAB"
"640.SVP - ARCHITECTURE & TECH SERVICES","ASSET MANAGEMENT"
"643.CORPORATE PROGRAMS PROJECT MANAGER III","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
"643.DIRECTOR - CIS PROGRAMS","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
"643.ENGINEER III - SECURITY ANALYST","PHYSICAL SECURITY"
"643.OPERATIONS ANALYST IV","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"643.PROJECT MANAGER IV","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
"643.PROJECT MANAGER VI","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
"643.SR MANAGER - SECURITY","PHYSICAL SECURITY"
"643.TECHNICAL PROJECT MANAGER III","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
"743.ASSET MGMT ANALYST III","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.ASSET MGMT ANALYST IV","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.BUSINESS OPERATIONS ANALYST III","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.DIRECTOR - DATA CENTER OPERATIONS","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.ENGINEER II - DATA CENTER OPS","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.ENGINEER II - TECHNICAL OPERATIONS","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.ENGINEER III - DATA CENTER OPS","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
"743.ENGINEER III - TECHNICAL OPERATIONS","DATA CENTER SERVICES"
```

1. parse the job title into the following - depending on the format above

   a. (Job Code).(Job Title) - Group
   b. (Job Code).(Job Title)
2. i want to separate these into separate entries in my dictionary (four of them)

   a. job code
   b. job title
   c. group+dept
   d. dept

I cant even get the regex to match, and i've tried regex tools and looked through the previous questions, with no luck.  i put my code below..

below is the relevant piece, and i cant figure out why the regex doesn't match..

"643.PROJECT MANAGER VI","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
"643.SR MANAGER - SECURITY","PHYSICAL SECURITY"
"643.TECHNICAL PROJECT MANAGER III","CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"

m = re.search ("\d+.\D+-\D+", string])

** it should match all of the values in the first field in the file above.

Comment: How about posting a simple, minimal question that clearly demonstrates a specific issue?  If you want help with a regex, post a sample input (just one or two) and the regex you're using.  Too much code here now.

Comment: @mixingbuddha: No, don't just update the bottom, rewrite your question so it has an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a whole mess of irrelevant stuff that people have to read through before finding your real question. Also, even with the update, I have no idea what `o`, `old_people[o]`, or `old_people[o]['Job Title']` might be. I assume it's probably one of the strings you listed above, but which one is it supposed to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp looks like this:

```
"\d+\.\D+-\D+"
```

I'm not sure what string you're trying to match, but apparently it's one of these:

1. "643.PROJECT MANAGER VI"
2. "CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"
3. "643.SR MANAGER - SECURITY"
4. "PHYSICAL SECURITY"
5. "643.TECHNICAL PROJECT MANAGER III",
6. "CORPORATE INFORMATION SERVICES"

The third one does match, so that can't be the one you're complaining about.

The even ones obviously aren't going to match because they don't start with digits.

So I assume it's either #1 or #5 that surprises you. Neither of them have a `-` in them, so they're not going to match.

---

A few side notes:

`-` is a member of the `\D` class, which is probably going to lead to confusion if you don't use `?` to change the greediness.

You really should be using raw strings (or escape the backslashes, if you prefer); the fact that `d` and `D` happen to not be in the current set of backslash escape characters is not something you want to rely on (especially if you want other people, who may not have that list memorized, to read your code).

If you're trying to parse these things into separate pieces, you don't want to match the whole thing, you want to add capturing groups.

Also, I assume the spaces aren't supposed to be part of the parsed strings, right?

So, your regexp should probably be something like:

```
r"(\d+)\.(\D+?)\s*-\s*(\D+)"
```

For example:

```
>>> s = "643.SR MANAGER - SECURITY"
>>> m = re.search(r"(\d+)\.(\D+?)\s*-\s*(\D+)", s)
>>> print(m.groups())
('643', 'SR MANAGER', 'SECURITY')
```